# POST an Issue to Github using iron-ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, github-api

even if I found some articles simliar to my problem no answer solved my problem:

I want to every (annonymous) user allow to post issues to Github. As I already develop using Polymer and Webcomponents I wanted to do this using `<iron-ajax>` so I have the `<iron-ajax>` element:

```
<iron-ajax
  id="githubIssues"
  url="https://api.github.com/repos/IchordeDionysos/social-contacts/issues"
  method="POST"
  params='{"access_token": "efd925cc3c8d593b720f0d6a88f3c36f593e063a"}'
  body="[[params]]"
  verbose
  handle-as="json"
  on-response="showSuccess">

</iron-ajax>
```

And I defined the params property like this:

```
params: {
  notify: true,
  type: Object,
  value: {
    "title": "",
    "body": "",
    "assignee": "IchordeDionysos",
    "labels": ["0 - Backlog"]
  }
}
```

And finally I have a button which call's a function to post the issue, in this function I check serveral `<paper-checkboxes>` if they are checked and if I push further labels to the params:

```
submitIssue: function() {
    if (this.$.bug.checked) {
      this.push('params.labels', 'bug');
    };
    if (this.$.help.checked) {
      this.push('params.labels', 'help');
    };
    if (this.$.question.checked) {
      this.push('params.labels', 'question');
    };
    if (this.$.feature.checked) {
      this.push('params.labels', 'feature');
    };
    if (this.$.enhancement.checked) {
      this.push('params.labels', 'enhancement');
    };
    if (this.$.design.checked) {
      this.push('params.labels', 'design');
    };
    console.log(this.params);
    this.$.githubIssues.generateRequest();
}
```

But when I try to post the the issue I get an `400 (Bad Request)`

How can I solve this and which scopes I have to grant to my token?

EDIT: Here is how my request header and body look like: http://requestb.in/11y0i0x1?inspect

EDIT: The [object Object] send to the body looks like this:

```
{title: "dsggsdf", 
 body: "sdfgsdfsdf", 
 assignee: "IchordeDionysos", 
 labels: Array[3]}
```

and the labels Array:

```
labels: Array[3]
  0: "0 - Backlog"
  1: "help"
  2: "question"
```

when I log the Object to the Chrome console

Comment: A 400 status code doesn't indicate a problem with scopes. Instead of calling the GitHub API, can you instead make a request to a request bin (http://requestb.in/), and then post here how the request headers and the body look exactly? That should help with figuring out what's the problem

Comment: I've posted a link to requestb.in

Comment: Thanks. As you can see -- the raw body is empty and the content-length is 0. This indicates that you're not sending the body correctly. And that's probably the reason why the API is responding with a 400.

Comment: Okay, I've made some changes and now I'm seeing In the body section that I'm sending an `[object Object]` and content-length isn't 0 anymore!

Comment: That's still not good -- that means that the raw string that you're sending to the GitHub API is `[object Object]` instead of a JSON object. It seems that you didn't serialize your object into a JSON string correctly.

Comment: Thanks you helped me a lot to understand, how server requests work. This was my first time I did something like this and I'm happy taht it is working right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the attribute `contentType="application/json"`

Like this:

```
<iron-ajax
  id="githubIssues"
  url="https://api.github.com/repos/IchordeDionysos/social-contacts/issues"
  method="POST"
  params='{"access_token": "efd925cc3c8d593b720f0d6a88f3c36f593e063a"}'
  body="[[params]]"
  verbose
  handle-as="json"
  on-response="showSuccess"
  contentType="application/json">    
</iron-ajax>
```

I hope this works ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the attribute `content-type="application/json"` to your iron-ajax attribute!

Without the `content-type` - attribute ajax would send the data provided in the `body` - attribute as a String and not as a json Object as you has to post to Github!